# How to get text from torchtext.data.dataset.Dataset

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

How can get the training data as text (or list of texts) from PyTorch Dataset(<torchtext.data.dataset.Dataset>) Object ?

Or more specifically from torchtext.datasets.IMDB

---

For example from [torchtext.datasets](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datasets.html#torchtext-datasets) (IMDB)

```
# make splits for data
train, test = datasets.IMDB.splits(TEXT, LABEL)
```

Assuming I did all steps on the documantation untill here, how can I get the first text in Dataset Object `train` as tuple in form of ("review", classification):

```
print(first_review)
```

```
Output:
('This is a great movie',  1)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you using `torchtext.datasets` or your own data?

Comment: Im using torchtext.datasets not my own dataset, and explicitly torchtext.datasets.IMDB. Also which part is unclear ? I can edit and be more specific on that part